# Help with windows TCP Port communication

Tags: c#, windows, networking, network-protocols, tcplistener

I'm new to understanding how interprocess communication works. I"m working with two applications on my localmachine, a Source Application and a Server Application. The Source application broadcasts files through a configured port on my pc. The Server application listens for those files and exposes them to the internet for users to stream.

I want to remove the Server application from the equation and write a new application to communicate with the Source application.

So far I have my application connected to the port and listening. I am able to receive a message from the port. The message i am receiving appears to be metadata, no file. My assumption is the Server Application sends a response once it has picked up this metadata information to obtain the file. Therefore my application needs to mimic the server application. However I have no idea how to respond to the source application's port.

1) Is there a tool I can use to monitor the communication between the Source application and the server application? I believe this would be a tool to watch for tcp messages? All the tools I come across appear to only look for http messages. Would a packet analyzer be of any use?

2) If I can't view the communication between the source and the server application, what else can I do? Is there a tool I can use to broadcast the meta information I"m receiving on a port, then point the server application to that port and receive a response?

Any resources to help me better understand this intercomunication process would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en), very easy to use.

Comment: I'm having the same issues with this as I am with wireshark. What do I need to do to capture interprocess communication on port 8080?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).  It can monitor any TCP (and mucn more) communication, including local.

Comment: Look for **Follow TCP Stream** menu.

Comment: It appears I can only see internet traffic. It's not showing any local traffic. I'm trying to watch the traffic on port 8080. I added a filter to see TCP.PORT = 8080 but then I see nothing. I feel like my interface be wrong. I have it hooked into my wireless adapter, what do I need to do to capture interprocess communication on port 8080?

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like Windows may not support capturing local traffic on the loopback interface.  See this chart (http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/NetworkMedia)

Comment: Looks like the microsoft network monitor has a MS TCP loopback interface. But when I turn this on it shows nothing.